# Проблема с пагинацией на WordPress

Tags: wordpress, pagination

Проблема заключается в том, что страниц выводится намного больше, чем статей в рубрике. Использую  WP-Paginate, на всех страницах вывод правильный, на одной-единственной нет, код вызова новостей ниже. Что делать?

```
<?php
// 1 значение по умолчанию
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
'posts_per_page' => 4,
'category_name'  => 'problems',
'paged'          => $paged,
) );

// цикл вывода полученных записей
while( $the_query->have_posts() ){
    $the_query->the_post();
    ?>
<div class="item3 flex-start">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(223,135)); ?>
    <div class="itwrap">
    <p class="title-item3"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
              </div>
  </div>
<?php 
} 
wp_reset_postdata();

?>
<?php if(function_exists('wp_paginate')) {

wp_paginate();

} ?>
```

Comment: Вместо `$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;` стОит писать `$paged = get_query_var( 'paged', 1 );`

Comment: Спасибо, ответ решил проблему, изменю в проекте и этот пункт. Самое интересное что ошибка была только на 1 странице.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_paginate()` по-умолчанию выводит список страниц исходя из результатов основного запроса. Соответсвенно если вы выполняете кастомный запрос и хотите сделать переход по его страницам нужно указать количество страниц в вызове `wp_paginate()`. Например для вашего случая:

```
wp_paginate(array('pages' => $the_query->max_num_pages, 'page' => $paged));
```